# Keycloak 7.0.0 standalone.sh startup error : IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak

I'm trying to run Keycloak standalone application server downloaded from the keycloak website. I haven't made any changes in any configuration file and just ran the standalone.sh file as instructed in the official documentation.

On running the standalone.sh file, I'm getting the error ([full debug log](https://pste.eu/p/KFJq.html)). It runs successfully sometimes but majority of the times I'm facing the above issue. I'm new to Java development, went through different forums and the maximum I could understand was that the issue exists due to database problems. Any advice how to rectify this issue?

[**Full Debug Logs**](https://pste.eu/p/KFJq.html)

Small snippet of the error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
```

You can view the standalone config file [here](https://pastebin.com/nC398G73).

Comment: The relevant part seems to be `java.net.UnknownHostException: host-176-43-4-84.reverse.superonline.net` , maybe some DNS problem ?

Comment: @Arnaud I don't think so, my other colleagues are able to run the same Keycloak standalone version on Windows whereas I'm on Ubuntu. Does that seem like a DNS issue?

Comment: @UtkarshGupta can you add standalone config file

Comment: @Batuhan I've edited the question description and added the config file at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is the problem, but i can suggest somethings(paragraph is little long so that, i did not write as comment). 
Logs says that, "host-176-43-4-84.reverse.superonline.net" address can not reachable. ("Name or service not known") **(I think, it is your machine dns name. am it ?)**

Keycloak uses default db as h2. (embeded on localhost). Logs says that, while keycloak try to up, it can not connect h2. Maybe editing host file can be solve this issue. Try to add "127.0.0.1 host-176-43-4-84.reverse.superonline.net" on host file.

***poorly possibile*** => if path of keycloak folder (keycloak dir) contains characters like "- _" , maybe it can be affect.

Comment: This might be the reason. The place where I was getting this error is behind a proxy/firewall(workplace network). When I tried the same from my home's network on the same machine, it worked. Hence marking the answer accepted.